# 4 table join and finding the average of a column

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I have 4 tables like this

- User [id, name, .....]
- Restaurant [id, name, .....]
- Review [restaurant_id, user_id]
- Question [id, review_id, score]

  application logic=>
  for every restaurants people can give review, review has some questions,
  questions would be always same- like how was the taste, delivery etc.people would give score on those questions.

in words, users gives reviews on restaurants against some questions

Now in my web app, i want to show there a list of restaurants with their `"Question table's score average"`.

I am using laravel. Eloquent query builder would help too.
I would like to have a computed field as average_rating with the total restaurants data.

Comment: do you need query in sql or Eloquent?

Comment: any would help actually

Comment: mysql to be specific

Answer (score 0):

You need nothing but a standard INNER JOIN among these four tables as the following :

```
SELECT rs.name, avg(qt.score) 
  FROM Restaurant rs 
  JOIN Review rv ( rv.restaurant_id = rs.id )
  JOIN User ur ( ur.id = rv.user_id )
  JOIN Question qt ON ( qt.review_id = rv.id )
 GROUP BY rs.name 
 ORDER BY avg(qt.score) desc, rs.name;
```

The theory may be explained as :

- all ***reviews*** are arranged for ***restaurants***
- we're concerned with the ***users*** those are in ***reviews*** about ***restaurants***
- all ***reviews*** contain ***questions*** in it.

Comment: ok, i am trying that out. why should the above query work?? can you explain the set theory or anything that goes into sql

Comment: Without group by it giving only the frist restaurant

Comment: hey @Barbaros thanks, you know questions will be same for all reviews, wouldn't make a problem????

Comment: thank you too, not problem using `average` solves, and we need `score` column of `Question` table.